# How to work around VIS Timeline group ordering bug in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timeline, vis.js

[Vis.js Timeline](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/) has a bug in Chrome (only). It changes the ordering of groups when there are more than 10 groups (trucks).

In [this exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/parhum/rcsrfaka/) in Chrome browser **Truck 11** display in first row and **Truck 2** display after **Truck 10**. In other browsers the ordering of groups are correct.

How can I make Chrome display the groups in the right order?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/parhum/rcsrfaka/

**HTML Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.9.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.9.0/vis.min.css">
<div id="js__timeline"></div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
<script>
  /**
   * Get URL parameter
   * http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
   */
  function gup( name ) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
    if( results == null )
      return "";
    else
      return results[1];
  }

  // get selected item count from url parameter
  var count = (Number(gup('count')) || 1000);

  // create groups
  var groups = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'Truck&nbsp;1'},
    {id: 2, content: 'Truck&nbsp;2'},
    {id: 3, content: 'Truck&nbsp;3'},
    {id: 4, content: 'Truck&nbsp;4'},
    {id: 5, content: 'Truck&nbsp;5'},
    {id: 6, content: 'Truck&nbsp;6'},
    {id: 7, content: 'Truck&nbsp;7'},
    {id: 8, content: 'Truck&nbsp;8'},
    {id: 9, content: 'Truck&nbsp;9'},
    {id: 10, content: 'Truck&nbsp;10'},
    {id: 11, content: 'Truck&nbsp;11'},
    {id: 12, content: 'Truck&nbsp;12'},
    {id: 13, content: 'Truck&nbsp;13'},
    {id: 14, content: 'Truck&nbsp;14'},
    {id: 15, content: 'Truck&nbsp;15'},
    {id: 16, content: 'Truck&nbsp;16'},
    {id: 17, content: 'Truck&nbsp;17'},
    {id: 18, content: 'Truck&nbsp;18'},
    {id: 19, content: 'Truck&nbsp;19'},
    {id: 20, content: 'Truck&nbsp;20'},
    {id: 21, content: 'Truck&nbsp;21'}
  ]);

  // create items
  var items = new vis.DataSet();

  var order = 1;
  var truck = 1;
  for (var j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
    var date = new Date();
    for (var i = 0; i < count/10; i++) {
      date.setHours(date.getHours() +  4 * (Math.random() < 0.2));
      var start = new Date(date);

      date.setHours(date.getHours() + 2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*4));
      var end = new Date(date);

      items.add({
        id: order,
        group: truck,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        content: 'Order ' + order
      });

      order++;
    }
    truck++;
  }

  // specify options
  var options = {
    stack: false,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(1000*60*60*24 + (new Date()).valueOf()),
    editable: true,
    margin: {
      item: 10, // minimal margin between items
      axis: 5   // minimal margin between items and the axis
    },
    orientation: 'top'
  };

  // create a Timeline
  var container = document.getElementById('js__timeline');
  timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, null, options);
  timeline.setGroups(groups);
  timeline.setItems(items);

  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;
</script>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to include an actual question in your post. Are you asking if this is indeed a bug? Are you asking how to work around it? Also, please include relevant code in the question instead of just posting it on external sites. Thank you.

Comment: @Anders Bug is related to Chrome browser, that changed ordering of group. I didn't copy any code in this  question because my code isn't important thing the bug is related to Vis Timeline JS not my code

Comment: This is a forum for Questions and Answers. You need to ask a question. Right now, you are just stating that there is a bug. That is a statement, not a question. Please edit your post so it contains an actual question. And I am quite sure that question will need code to be answered. Why else would you bother to put the code on an external site?

Comment: @Anders I completed my question. please help me

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also include a question? What is it that you are asking?

Comment: @Anders :) Is not clear? I want solve my problem in chrome browser. correct ordering. how ask my question? Can you help me?

Comment: I edited the question to include the question you asked. Since it has been edited, it should be added to the reopen queue and once a sufficient number of people with enough reputation has said it looks good (which I think it does) the question will be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you haven't defined any ordering for the groups, leaving their order undetermined.

You can either set the option groupOrder to 'id' to have the groups ordered by their id, or provide your own sorting function there, or give all groups a property order.

From the docs on groupOrder:

> Order the groups by a field name or custom sort function. By default,
>   groups are ordered by a property order (if set). If no order
>   properties are provided, the order will be undetermined.

https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1399